# Can I convert a JSON property (not full JSON) to csv with DataWeave without parsing it first to an Apex class?

Tags: apex, json, csv, dataweave

It's been very easy with DataWeave in Apex to convert a JSON to a csv.
However, I'm getting a JSON from a REST call, and the part I'm interested in is located in the "data" property, something like that (simplified):

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 2854701,
            "person": "6116"
        },
        {
            "id": 2854702,
            "person": "6116"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do I have a way to only use the content of the data property for the DataWeave transformation ? I guess I could create an Apex class to parse everything, keep only the data part and parse it again to csv but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would have better read the [DataWeave documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/dataweave-reference-documentation) before asking before it turns out it's damn simple, I was just not understanding how DataWeave works and its syntax.

Whereas the basic .dwl file I had to convert json to csv was like this:

```
%dw 2.0 
input payload application/json
output application/csv
--- 
payload
```

I just had to change the latest part of the script to select what's exported:

```
%dw 2.0 
input payload application/json
output application/csv
--- 
payload.data
```

So it's actually a pretty stupid question, but as DataWeave is coming to Apex and I guess some other folks may be as new to it as I am, this may be useful to another "I don't read the doc long enough" fellow like me.

To experiment the [DataWeave Playground](https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/playground) is definitely a great tool.